# how to track changes in database

Tags: c#

I am developing a windows form application using C#. I am showing a grid with values comes from database.
My question is how to update grid when changes are made in database by means of any method.

I have tried [SqlDependency class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). But, my grid gets refresh continuously and i don't need it to refresh. 
Is there any other way to track changes in database? 
Is it possible to update data set if any one made changes in database?

Comment: there is server log in SQL Server...

Comment: to read server log i will have to write thread in c# which will continuously hit database, is it correct?

Comment: server log is file-based.

Comment: where will i get that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Open-Source class [SqlDependencyEx](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener). It is pretty easy to configure and use:

```
int changesReceived = 0;
using (SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(
          TEST_CONNECTION_STRING, TEST_DATABASE_NAME, TEST_TABLE_NAME)) 
{
    sqlDependency.TableChanged += (o, e) => changesReceived++;
    sqlDependency.Start();

    // Make table changes.
    MakeTableInsertDeleteChanges(changesCount);

    // Wait a little bit to receive all changes.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

Assert.AreEqual(changesCount, changesReceived);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Check [Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx) that were introduced in SQL Server 2005. Query Notifications allow applications to be notified when data has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement SQLServer notification, instead of polling which you must be doing currently, so it refreshes the grid after a particular interval of time.

using service broker and SqlCacheDependency, you can achieve it, you can go through this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144344/Query-Notification-using-SqlDependency-and-SqlCach) to implemnt it.